# Swift show button to refresh table like in twitter

Tags: swift, swift2

Please can someone tell me how I get a button to appear if there are new information like in twitter 'more tweets'
Just would like to know the coding to show the button and make the button disappear
Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: If you want this, getting the button there is least of your worries.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach called "Pull to Refresh". Adding the button is one of many steps you will need to take in order to apply this functionality. There are many good tutorials over the web for how to do it, here are few:

- https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2015/03/17/basics-of-pull-to-refresh-for-swift-developers/
- https://grokswift.com/pull-to-refresh-swift-table-view/
- https://www.appcoda.com/custom-pull-to-refresh/

Comment: Thanks everyone else too :)